# Como acessar dados vindo do formulário em orientação a objetos

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Como faço para receber informações vindo de POST do formulário, para que esses dados entrem em uma estrutura de decisão, Exemplo: tenho uma classe abstrata com a função de entrar no sistema, porem no formulário o usuário tem que marcar se ele é funcionário ou entregador, a classe que herda o método entrar antes de mais nada precisa saber se esse login se trata do funcionário da empresa ou do entregador, pois ambos serão direcionados para telas diferentes.

```
PAGINA INDEX, NÃO COLOQUEI O FORMULARIO PARA NÃO FICAR EXTENSO DEMAIS.
```

require_once 'Logar.php';

$logando = new Logar($usuario, $senha);
$logando ->setUsuario($_POST['usuario']);
$logando->setSenha($_POST['senha']);

PAGINA LOGIN:

```
public function __construct($usuario, $senha) {
    $this->usuario = $usuario;
    $this->senha = $senha;

}

function getUsuario() {
    return $this->usuario;
}

function getSenha() {
    return $this->senha;
}

function setUsuario($usuario) {
    $this->usuario = $usuario;
}

function setSenha($senha) {
    $this->senha = $senha;
}


abstract public function Entrar($usuario, $senha);
abstract public function Sair();     
abstract public function Erro();
```

}

PAGINA LOGAR

class Logar extends Login {

```
private $con;

public function __construct($usuario, $senha) {
    parent::__construct($usuario, $senha);
    $this->con = new Conexao();
}


public function Entrar($usuario, $senha) {
    parent::Entrar($usuario, $senha);
    echo "Método entrar esta funcionando";
}

public function Sair(){
    echo "Saindo";
}

public function Erro() {
    echo "Erro";
}
```

}

Comment: creio que não seja essa a forma correta, uma vez que sua classe tem de ter um objetivo específico, na hora que vc criar o objeto `Logar`, passe os dados do `$_POST['varx']` para o método `Entrar`

Comment: E não esqueça de usar `filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);` para evitar injection

Comment: A sua lógica está confusa e parece que está aprendendo POO e é isso que está te atrapalhando nesse contexto minimo não tem como dizer o que precisa fazer, geralmente tem mais coisas a se fazer ( eu acho pelo pouco que vi).

Comment: Estou começando a aprende POO e não encontrei nenhum artigo na internet que ensine como receber dados vindo de POST

Answer (score 1):

Tente deixar seu método assim:

```
public function Entrar() 
{
    echo $this->getUsuario() . ' - ' . $this->getSenha(); // Imprime usuário e senha recebidos p/ testar
}
```

Já no objeto, no escopo onde está sendo executado seu código, você chama o método `Entrar()` se a condição for verdadeira:

```
if (isset($_POST['botao']) && $_POST['botao'] == 'Login Funcionário')
{
    $obj = new Logar(); // Instancia o objeto da classe Logar

    $obj->setUsuario($_POST['usuario']); // Atribui usuário
    $obj->setSenha($_POST['senha']); // Atribui senha
    $obj->Entrar(); // Chama o método Entrar()
}
```

Não esqueça de tratar os dados vindos do `$_POST`.

---

### EDIT:

`$usuario` e `$senha` são dados vindo do `$_POST`? Você está atribuindo esses valores à essas variáveis antes?

Se sim, então se você está passando `$usuario` e `$senha` para o método construtor, logo não é necessário passar de novo chamando: `$logando->setUsuario($_POST['usuario']);` e `$logando->setSenha($_POST['senha']);`, porque lá você chama o `__construct()` da classe-mãe e já atribui os valores às propriedades.

Outra coisa que encontrei é no seu método `Entrar()` da classe-filha (Logar). Nela você está chamando o método `Entrar()` da classe-mãe que é abstrato através do `parent::Entrar($usuario, $senha);`, ou seja, não tem funcionalidades implementadas.

Comment: Entendi Paulo mas como eu recebo as variaveis vindo do formulário via POST? como eu declaro nas variaveis abaixo que os valores dela vem de um formulario?


$usuário = $_POST['usuario'];
$senha = $_POST['senha']:

Desta forma gera o Erro: Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\Exemplo1\Logar.php on line 11

Comment: Considerando que você tem os *Getters* e *Setters* públicos na classe-mãe, você pode fazer assim com seu objeto: `$obj->setUsuario($_POST['usuario']);` e `$obj->setSenha($_POST['senha']);`. Dessa forma, você vai poder acessar os atributos na classe-filha através do `$this->getUsuario();` e `$this->getSenha();` em qualquer método que desejar, já que `$usuario` e `$senha` são `protected`.

Comment: Editei a resposta, dá uma olhada pra ver se te ajuda melhor.

Comment: Não deu certo esta me gerando este erro:


Notice: Undefined variable: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\Programas_Orientacao_Obj\Casa_Das_Marmitas\index.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined variable: senha in C:\xampp\htdocs\Programas_Orientacao_Obj\Casa_Das_Marmitas\index.php on line 4

Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\Programas_Orientacao_Obj\Casa_Das_Marmitas\index.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: senha in C:\xampp\htdocs\Programas_Orientacao_Obj\Casa_Das_Marmitas\index.php on line 6

Comment: Posta seu código atualizado, por favor.

Comment: Editei o código da pergunta

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta. Dê uma olhada.

Comment: Agora deu certo obrigada ficou muito bem explicado.

Comment: Que bom! Precisando estamos por aí.